# Keyboard signal handling, adding parameters to callback handler function (Ubuntu, intel)

Tags: c, keyboard, signals, signal-handling

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

// Define the function to be called when ctrl-c (SIGINT) signal is sent to process
void
signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
   // Cleanup and close up stuff here

   // Terminate program
   exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
   // Register signal and signal handler
   signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);

   while(1)
   {
      printf("Program processing stuff here.\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is there a way to pass an extra argument in the callback function?
Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

// Define the function to be called when ctrl-c (SIGINT) signal is sent to process
void
signal_callback_handler(int signum, int k)
{

   k++; // Changing value of k
}

int main()
{
   int k = 0;
   // Register signal and signal handler
   signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler(k);

   while(1)
   {
      printf("Program processing stuff here.\n");
      printf(" blah %d\n", k);
      sleep(1);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not, and there's very little that you should actually be *doing* in a signal handler anyway.

I generally just set a flag and return, letting the real code handle it from then on.

If you really wanted to do that, you could make `k` a file-level static so that both `main` and the signal handler (and every other function in the file) could access it, but you might want to investigate the safety of that option (whether a signal handler can run while the real program is using or updating the value).

In other words, something like:

```
static int k = 0;

void signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
   k++; // Changing value of k
}

int main() {
   // Register signal and signal handler
   signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
   : :
```

Comment: using a general variable? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Even then, the shared variable should either be of type `sig_atomic_t` or you should carefully block signals around critical sections (relative to the mutation of the data shared between the program and the signal handler) as appropriate. See ["Signal Handling"](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Atomic-Data-Access.html#Atomic-Data-Access) in the GNU C library documentation.

Comment: Also note that it is possible for your program to be signaled before it has a chance to install its signal handler. You are in effect racing the signaler. This is why you should ensure your signal handlers are in place prior to doing anything else.